# Is it possible to identify from where(mobile device or printout) the bar code has been scanned from

Tags: c#, java

While writing a native kiosk application one of the requirements that came up. While scanning the bar code with a 2D/QR code scanner, I've to identify if the bar code scanned was present on a mobile device(Passbook, etc) or was it on a printout. Is it possible to identify from where(mobile device or printout) the bar code has been scanned from, any tools which can do it?

Last option would be to have some sort of values in the bar/QR code during generation to differentiate them one for mobile devices and one for the physical mediums.

Answer (score 1):

No that's not possible, 2 options:

- Use 2 different barcodes, which will - in your system - lead to the same endpoint but can show the difference between a printout and a mobile scanned barcode.
- Let the user that scans the barcode choose if it was scanned from a mobile device or a printout.